# Error with matlines function

Tags: r, plot, glm

I would be very thankful for any advice on this error I get with my `matlines()`. Here is some mock data

```
al<-seq(1,65)
d<-seq(1,65)
r<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c",)
v<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c")
lq<-seq(1,65)
data11<-data.frame(al,d,r,v,lq)
```

Here is the model and the extracted predicted values.

```
m11<-glm(formula = al ~ r+log(d) + v +offset(lq), family = poisson, data = data11);summary(m11)
p22<-predict(m11,newdata=data11,se.fit=TRUE,type="response")
data11<- data.frame(data11,p22)
```

And then trying to plot it.

```
plot(al~d, data=data11, pch=as.character(v))
y <- unstack(mydata, mydata$fit~mydata$vegetation)
x <- unstack(data11, data11$d~data11$v)
matlines(x,y)
```

But I receive this error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log = log) :
>   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: `unstack` returns a list. `matlines` only accepts vectors or matrices as input.

Comment: @Roland How could I write x and y as vectors?